# How to attach files and folders with AWS Lambda Handler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron

I have an AWS Lambda

```
service: serverlesslambda
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
functions:
  changeWeeklyStarterStatus:
    handler: handler.changeWeeklyStarterStatus
    schedule: cron(0 0 0 ? * SUN *)
```

And its Handler :

```
"use strict";

module.exports.changeWeeklyStarterStatus = async event => {

  // TODO : Put the logic of the handler here

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(
      {
        message: `TODO ...`,
        input: event
      },
      null,
      2
    )
  };
};
```

Please notice the line :

> // TODO : Put the logic of the handler here

I need to connect to mongo and run a query , for that I've created a few files and folders :

> ```
> config folder
> -db.js - mongo connection
> -production.json - params and connection string
> -default.json - localhost params
>
> modules folder 
> -EmployeesSchema - A collection that I run the queries on
>
> utils folder
> DateUtil.js - dates manipulation 
> LambdaUtils.js - the actual query that I run on `EmployeesSchema`
> ```

How do I upload all that to AWS and actually use those files with the Lambda Handler ?

Comment: I would take a look at the documentation. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking , how do you deploy these files to AWS, you can keep the files inside your project and deploy your project.

By default, the serverless framework will include the files in the directory where serverless.yml is. This is not true if you use plugins like `serverless-webpack`, because such plugins only include what's being used (referred by other files)

Comment: Is that what you want to know